Is there a best or most natural key for a guitar in standard tuning?
Many musical instruments have a preferred key. Even the piano, which like the guitar can be played in any key, may be easier to play in some key signatures because of the physical layout and size difference of the keys.
The guitar is tuned to the Em (i.e G major) pentatonic scale but playing something nice with only open strings is not easy because E low to E high covers two octaves and the order of the notes is not felicitous. But, the tuning does make some chords very easy: Em7 (i.e. G6/E) and lots of others. So is there a ‘best’ key for the guitar? I’ll ignore what the capo does (it shortens the fretboard!).
It seems to me that the best key for standard tuning is A because A, D and E7 are all ‘beginner’ chords and although the F#m which would occur in lots of songs is a bit tricky, lots of easy songs use the closely related key of Am with various other easy chords. I assume that open strings are easier and barre chords are for more advanced players. Also the A minor and major pentatonic scales, while they can be played in any position, have a good home on the 5th fret which is a comfortable place half way up the 1-12 fretboard. So is the best key A? It does not seem to be C major because F is a chord with more difficulty than the other ‘cowboy’ chords. It could of course be E major since B7 happens to be easy to play in first position, but B major is not. Other candidates may be D major and G major but clearly E♭ of C♯ are not likely to be the most guitar friendly keys and when we see those it’s time to reach for the capo.
So is there a natural key for the guitar, and if so, which is it?

For both piano and guitar, it depends on the skill level of the player. What skill level are you writing for?

Your assumption about the piano is incorrect. C is chosen for beginner pieces because it is easier to read in, but fingerings in other keys are more comfortable.  FWIW, I prefer A♭ or E♭ for something with a pure major quality. Irving Berlin famously prefered playing in F♯.

Thanks for the clarification @Theodore. My mistake, based on personal knowledge and playing experience (I'm clearly not a pianist). Hope I've fixed it, but the question is really about the guitar.

I’m not sure how to clarify the question in response to your comment @ToddWilcox. Is the suggestion that the easier keys change as we build our skills? If some key is easier for a beginner then I guess it would be always easier but more advanced players may notice no difference. This would be an answer, but I think a surprising one. The guitar is a physical device so would any differences not be measurable in terms of movements etc.? I expect what is easy also depends a lot on the style being played, e.g. if a style avoids open strings, but the question is about standard tuning, not genres.

The standard guitar tuning is not made to favor a specific key, it is designed to make chords easier to play, especially barre chords. If it were tuned in all perfect fourths, or perfect fifths, you'd need an extra finger or two to play chords in the middle of the fretboard.
There are keys that are easier than others (for chords), but there isn't a key where all chords are easy (simple open chords).
If we assume that in major the most common chords are I, IV, V, and VI, then G major is the only key I can think of where all these chords are open chords (G, C, D, and Em).
In minor keys, even in pop music, there is a greater variety of chords that tend to be used: I, III, IV, V (both minor and major), VI, VII. Basically everything except the the diminished II chord. Notice that, III, VI, and VII are also the I, IV, V of the relative major.
In E minor, practically all these chords are easy to play (Em, G, Am, B7, C, D). That only leaves the Vm chord and V chord (triad) requiring barre chords, but Vm is relatively uncommon and V can often be replaced by a V7 (B7 in this case, which is an open chord) with little overall impact.
A and Am are good when you only have I, IV, and V chords (E, A, D), e.g. for blues (the 7 chords are also open), but not just blues. I, IV, and V are the most important chords in any key. A minor especially has a lot of open chords, if you don't need a VI, all that's left are easy open chords. The only thing I dislike in A is that the bass note of the IV and V are so far apart (open E and open D). You also get a easy V7/V in A/Am (B7), which is a very common secondary dominant.
If you need to switch between relative minor and major keys Em and G are the easiest combo, if you need to switch between parallel minor an major keys, A and Am are interesting.
TL;DR: Em and G are arguably the easiest keys on guitar for chords. A is nice because it works in both minor and major as long as it's mostly I, IV, V chords.

C may not be the easiest on piano - I know a couple, at least, of self taught piano players who prefer F♯, as that incorporates all the black keys. C tends to get chosen in tutor books as it obviates the use of accidentals, I guess.
On guitar, it's obvious that some songs were written on guitar, therefore were guitar orientated. And yes, the keys you mention are ripe for that.
The first chords I teach students are E A and B7, as there is very little movement for fingers, and hardly any for wrist/arm. None in some of those changes. So maybe those are the candidates. Bring D into the equation, and it needs a lot of articulation to move to and from the three main chords of A D and E.
Certainly agree that C is not a favourite, as sooner or later, the dreaded F raises its head. C>G isn't bad at all though.
Got a feeling there's not going to be a definitive answer to this one, but it'll be interesting to  how folk plead their case.
Against all this, non-chord-wise, Em and G work best, with a nice pattern, using all the open strings, when playing melodies, especially pentatonics...

Self-taught pianist here.  I find a few flats to be quite nice: e.g. B♭, E♭, or A♭.  I think that C is popular with beginners just because it is easier to read.  I knew how to read music before attempting the piano so I had no reason to prefer C.  Also, self-taught guitarist and E, A, and B7 were my first chords.

Thanks @badjohn for pointing out my rookie error. I'm not a pianist, and based that comment on my (very limited) personal experience. I like either all white or all black best, and that has nothing to do with reading music. Have changed the question in response to your and Tim's comments.

There really is not an objective answer to this question, because there isn't any criteria for what you are trying to make "natural", or what I assume you mean as "easy."
If you considered the open strings of standard tuning and what all of them to always be "in key", then the keys are C, G, and D major. Any other keys, including all minor keys using a proper leading tone, will require a sharp or flat on at least one of the open strings.
This doesn't mean there can't be easy music in the other keys. Limiting to just those three keys is a strategy to make any errant playing of an open string not terribly out of tune and an obvious mistake. Given your idea of "natural key" this approach at least answers the question in terms of pitches in the key and the general idea that open strings are easy to play.
But, the playing techniques used will have more impact on the difficulty level.

So is the best key A? It does not seem to be C major because F is a chord with more difficulty than the other ‘cowboy’ chords.

I agree, but why is playing an F chord (presumably a barre chord or "E form" down at the first fret) now a requirement? This changes the question from one about key to one about technique. I think you need to give a little more of the criteria for what you want to do. For example, if you wanted an open chord based piece in C major, and the F chord for a subdominant presents a technical challenge, just substitute it with an open Dm chord.
Getting back to keys. Moving in the direction of keys with flats certainly is inconvenient for open chords in standard tuning. From that perspective C major is "closer" to the keys with flats than G or D major and so is potentially a more "difficult" key. One reason G major is a good key in standard tuning is you get two adjacent keys, the dominant at D major and the subdominant at F, without any sharps or flats on the open strings. That allows for a nice flexible harmonic palette with common modulations.

It really depends on what you are optimizing for. My favorite tuning makes certain chord qualities impossible to play without going far up away from the nut, making the quality of the chord different. If you had a hand as big as the guitar the optimal tuning might be totally different, perhaps you would then prefer to have all strings tuned the same bass note even.


Many musical instruments have a preferred key.

Certainly, guitar is universal enough not to have a single most preferred key.

Even the piano, which like the guitar can be played in any key, is best in C

Apart from the most beginner level, this is not true.
Lots of classical repertoire uses keys between 2 flats (Bb/Gm) and 4 sharps (E/C#m), which allow using open strings. These keys can be seen as easier, but that's a quite big range. This could serve as the most basic guideline for choosing a playable key for a guitarist.

I have found the guitar for me is tuned to the key of C major.
Starting on low E6 string- open, you may begin the Phrygian double/horizontal  scale. This continues up the fretboard with the minimal amount of movement & minimal amount of effort in a very easy pattern for the modes. 
